# Lolin D32 Pro board with OLED SH1106

Tags: esp32

Just starting a project and wanting to connect Lolin D32 Pro board with OLED SH1106. The screeen works with my Arduino Nano no problem however I can't seem to get it working on the D32 Pro. 
I tried different pins on the D32 and different libraries, no luck.

My code example is below and I connect pin 21 of D32 board to the sda pin of the screen and pin 22 of the d32 board to the scl pin of the screen. VCC & GND also are connected correspondingly

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SH1106.h>

#define OLED_SDA 21
#define OLED_SCL 22

Adafruit_SH1106 display(21, 22);


void setup()   {                
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("setup");
  /* initialize OLED with I2C address 0x3C */
  display.begin(SH1106_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C); 
  Serial.println("begin");
  display.clearDisplay();
  Serial.println("clear");

}
void loop() { 
    Serial.println("loop");

  /* set text size, color, cursor position, 
  set buffer with  Hello world and show off*/
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(0,0);
  display.println("Hello, world!");
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();
}
```

Please help me out with the code example or something to read. I suspect I am missing something around D32 Pro board pins